# img url broken in php database retrieval

Tags: php, jquery, html, postgresql

This is a remarkably tricky issue for me to solve.  I'm looking at my PostgreSQL table, my PHP query, and my HTML, and common sense tells me this should work 100%.  The design goal is to iteratively show all photo thumbnails associated with a given record, and display a larger version of each image in a modal.  The thumbnails work, but the modal img URLs are only a directory (according to Chrome DevTools). What went wrong?  Feel free to ask clarifying questions, I intend to solve this today.

```
// Database Query Code
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=biopro user=biopro password=") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$record = $_POST['record'];
$search_db_photos = "SELECT res_key, res_filename FROM resources WHERE key_creator={$record} AND NOT res_type='pp' ORDER BY date_created DESC;";
$dbphotos = pg_query($search_db_photos);
```

...The actual gallery constructed with a loop. Again, thumbnails work, modals dont (meaning they popup as expected, but display a broken image link).

```
   if (pg_num_rows($dbphotos) !=0 ) {
           echo '    <div class="cover-container">';
        for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($dbphotos); $i++) {
        $resource=pg_fetch_row($dbphotos);
        echo<<<HERE
<div class="cover-item" style="background-image: url('uploads/{$resource[1]}')" onclick="Modal('pic{$i}')"></div>";
HERE;
    } // END for() 1 of 2
    echo '</div>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < pg_num_rows($dbphotos); $i++) {
        $resource=pg_fetch_row($dbphotos);

        echo<<<HERE
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modalpic{$i}">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
<img src="uploads/{$resource[1]}" alt="Img {$i}" class="uploadimg" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning pull-left" onclick="modResource('delete', '{$resource[0]}', '{$record}')">Delete</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="modResource('upgrade', '{$resource[0]}', '{$record}')">Set as Primary</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
HERE;
        } // END for()
    } // END if()
pg_close($dbconn);
} //END addPhotos()
addPhotos();
```

Output of `print_r($resource)`

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 13
    [1] => wildlife2.jpg
)
```

Terminal output of `psql`

```
=> SELECT res_filename FROM resources;
 res_filename  
---------------
 wildlife1.jpg
 wildlife1.jpg
 house.jpeg
 wildlife2.jpg
 house.jpeg
 ...
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the absolute path from your root including the host name: `<img src="http://www.domain.com/uploads/{$resource[1]}" ...etc`? Also when you view source in the browser is it what you expect?

Comment: Also your browser console should tell you what the error is (like 404 or 403 or whatever).

Comment: No console errors.  PHP is quietly returning nothing for a filename, even though the relative path is correct.  For whatever reason, in StackExchange's infinite wisdom, a comment was removed from this post that actually contained a valuable suggestion regarding the pg_result_seek function that may solve my problem. Since the $resource resultset is being used twice in separate loops, it may be that the internal pointer has reached the end before the matching modals are generated. Thus, empty strings for filenames.